# invisible not working for textview in android

Tags: android, visibility, textview

I am facing a problem where `invisible` parameter of the text view is not working, As I am still able to see the `textview` when viewing the app on device.

XML:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
```

Since this was not working I have applied the same in oncreate but still result is same.

```
Helptext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

And I am manuplicating below way using code:

```
if(cursora1.moveToNext())
{
    Helptext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
else
{
    Helptext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Any guess where I am going wrong.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Thanks for your response... checked cursor has data...thats where I am confused

Comment: highly unlikely. I would guess the textview you are hiding is not actually the one you want to hide. possible reason include calling `setContentView` several times.

Comment: Show a Toast inside that `if` condition and check whether the `if` is working...

Comment: @njzk2 thanks for your response but `setContentView` is called only once. Is there any other possibility?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

in your xml file and

```
Helptext.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

in your class

Comment: this is a different feature that has a different meaning.